# Strut Torque Specs for 2008 Toyota Camry Hybrid

Tags: toyota, camry, torque, struts, torque-specification

Can anybody provide what the Torque specs are for the front struts on a 2008 Toyota Camry Hybrid?  Google searches provide conflicting and incomplete information.  Was hoping someone had a repair manual that lists the exact specs for the 08.

Comment: If you are looking after your car, then a repair manual is a very good investment.

Comment: Looks like the official Toyota repair manual is hundreds of dollars and the Haynes manual is very cheap.  Will the Haynes manual cover most things?

Comment: Usually Haynes manuals are very good. I would check important details with other sources to confirm before leaping in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which fastener you are referring to, so here's the complete diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SteveRacer!  Just a general tip to anybody reading this from my experience today (newb, DIY).  Check the strut assembly instructions before you torque down the support bolts up top under the hood.  I snapped the bolts off on 2 different units (yes, had to make 2 trips to 2 different Advance Auto's to exchange.  Monroe Quick Struts) because I was using a big 1/2in torque wrench to torque it to 63 ft/lbs like the diagram says.  (Luckily, the bolts never snapped on the other (right) strut when I used the torque wrench). Upon reading the directions it says to hand tighten (with a regular ratchet) 3 turns.  So, third time was a charm. I tightened until they were snug with the regular ratchet.  I used some blue thread locker just to be safe.  The other bolts I torqued to spec, no problem.

Also, be sure to buy extra sway bar links even if you don't need them.  The hex thread was stripped on mine, so I had to cut the bolts with a sawzall on both links (4 bolts).  Time consuming and really awkward to fit a sawzall in the wheel well.  If you can get the link off without stripping the hex, then just return the sway bar links that you didn't use.  Better to have and not need.  Will save you a trip and some time.  Also, if you have something that can do a better job at cutting bolts than a sawzall, then please use it.  I tried my dremel rotary tool, but it was just too awkward to fit behind there (especially the bottom bolts into the sway bar).  It was tough to cut because the sawzall would also vibrate the sway bar, so the cut took much longer than it should have.

Hope others learn from my mistakes.  Took it for a test drive and it drives nice so far!